# Change ipv4 to automatically assign ip address

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, ip-address

In my virtual machine, I changed the ipv4 properties from automatically assign ip address to some specific address. It was a virtual machine. On changing the address, I am no longer able to connect to it remotely and I do not know how to change it back to automatically assign ip address. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

More information is required here:

- which virtual machine? Where does it run? Vmware? VBox? XEN? Amazon EC2?
- Which guest do you use?

In general, if you have a Linux guest OS (or other OS-es which use configuration files for this setting) , and it contains important content, you could start up another vm with shell access with the same OS, before you attach the drive from your problematic VM. Then edit the configuration file in the mounted drive. With root trights, this should be possible.

Then start up the other VM..

If it is running in EC2 or another remote system, I cannot really help you. But an admin of the hosting platform could do these steps. Drawback: He accesses your system, which might contain sensitive information.